# Invoking lock endpoint on the plutus-starter guessing game is giving me "endpoint not available" error

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

Using the nix-shell approach, I'm able to build and execute the plutus starter PAB project, which includes the guessing game contract. [GIT repo link](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter)

In a separate terminal window, I can run the GET request to see the contract definition.  The response shows the GameContract along with the schema, which has lock and guess endpoints.

I successfully call the activate endpoint for each of wallet1 and wallet2.

However, when I call the lock endpoint for wallet1 ID, it gives me the following error. If I look at the logs in the terminal, where the PAB is running, there is no evidence that an endpoint execution failed.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   --request POST \
>   --data '{"amount":{"getValue":[[{"unCurrencySymbol":""},[[{"unTokenName":""},90]]]]},"secretWord":"eagle"}' \
>   http://localhost:8080/api/new/contract/instance/2acb116b-5488-4672-99c2-f2940cfd7b3a/endpoint/lock

EndpointCallError (EndpointNotAvailable (ContractInstanceId {unContractInstanceId = 2acb116b-5488-4672-99c2-f2940cfd7b3a}) (EndpointDescription {getEndpointDescription = "lock"}))
```

The format of the API call appears correct.  Based on PAB docs, it should be

```
POST /api/new/contract/instance/:contract-instance-id/endpoint/:endpoint-name
```

Has anyone had this issue?  What am I missing?

Comment: I can reproduce this - it was happening prior recent [Plutus bump pull request](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter/pull/16) as well. I'm not sure what the root cause is yet - [week10 example from plutus-pioneers](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/week10) works.

Tests in plutus-starter pass as well but they don't call HTTP API at all. Check that pab executable logs `Exposing endpoint <name>` message as well (it does for me but I'm not able to call `lock`).